# preventDefault does not work with jQuery.live

Tags: jquery, live, preventdefault

I have this piece of JS:

```
$('.self_delete').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success:  $(this).parent().remove(),
        dataType: "script"
    })
});
```

which target this HTML:

```
<a href="/list_items/34" class="self_delete" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">
    <i class="icon-trash"></i>
</a>
```

The problem is that when I click on the link, it will first submit the ajax call to the server THEN is send the normal HTML call. Of course, this mess things up since the list_item is already deleted.

I have a feeling this is caused by the live() call, but I cant figure out why. My JS-Fu needs some training!

---

EDIT
changed the code to this:

```
$('.self_delete').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: self.attr('href'),
        success:  function(){ self.parent().remove() },
        dataType: "script"
    })
});
```

And I still have the same issue. Tried to replace .live with .on but it did not even try to submit via AJAX, so I guess I will have to read the doc more carefully :-S

Comment: you could use bind instead of live?

Comment: Actually `.live()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()`

Comment: @F.Calderan both `bind` and `live` are deprecated as of 1.4, use `on` for 1.7 or higher, or `delegate` for otherwise :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your success code in an anonymous function, at the moment it will run immediately, also store a reference to `$(this)` in another variable e.g `self`

```
$('.self_delete').live('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var self = $(this); 
$.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: self.attr('href'),
    success:  function(){ self.parent().remove() }, 
})
});
```

On a side note, you should be using `.on` as of jQuery 1.7 `.live` has been deprecated.

```
$(document).on('click', '.self_delete', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: self.attr('href'),
        success:  function(){ self.parent().remove() }, 
    })
});
```

Comment: +1 for spotting that, but how would that prevent the additional submit?

Comment: look above, problem still present.

Comment: What does **THEN it send the normal HTML call** mean. I guess i don't really understand what problem you're having, what are you expecting it to do ? In this case it will send the ajax request and on success it will remove the parent element.

Comment: oups... basically, it sends the JS request (from the AJAX call) then it sends the HTML request from clicking the link. It is as if the .preventDefault() did not work.

Comment: ok. decided to change my approach and scrap all that code. But I will give you the +1 for pointing out the success function wrap. thx